# Does python not recognize a variable that I use in an if statement that is also used in a for?

Tags: python, list

I'm a beginner in python,I come from a c++background. So when I pop an element out, I got to start over the list and make the i = 0. Pycharm is giving me an warning when I make `i = 0` that local variable `i` is not used, but is it local? If the if statement is in for, doesn't pycharm know that I'm referring to the variable I that I use in for?

```
 for i in range(0, len(animals)-1):
        if(i == 0 and animals[i]!="grass" and animals[i]!="leaves"):
            if animals[1]  in animals_dict[animals[0]]:
                a=animals.pop(1)
                animals_final.append(f"{animals[0]} eats {a}")
        elif(animals[i]!="grass" and animals[i]!="leaves"):
            if animals[i-1] in animals_dict[animals[i]]:
                a=animals.pop(i-1)
                i-=1
                animals_final.append(f"{animals[i]} eats {a}")
                i=0
            elif animals[i+1] in animals_dict[animals[i]] and i+1<=len(animals) :
                a=animals.pop(i+1)
                animals_final.append(f"{animals[i]} eats {a}")
                i=0`
```

Comment: Changing `i` in your loop is pointless.  The next iteration of the loop will assign `i` to the next value from the `range()` given on the first line, ignoring your changes.  To make a loop index that you can modify like this, you'd have to write a `while` loop instead.

Comment: You have to be careful modifying a collection that you are iterating over. Also, please always indicate which line of code a warning/error happens on, and include the exact message.

Comment: For a good illustration of what's actually happening in your code, try simplifying the loop to `for i in range(10): print("Iterator variable:",i);i=0;print("Assigned variable:",i)`

Comment: Thank a lot, I think I read somewhere that range is like a generator?

Comment: @SoareStefan  Yes, a range is a generator.  But list or generator doesn't make any difference here.  You still cannot change the value of the next iteration by any mechanism within your loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`range` is a special object type, and its iterators have their own state. Setting `i = 0` doesn't change the fact that the range iterator will replace `i` with the next value "on deck" (so to speak) when the `for` loops again (this is a general trait of all `for` loops, but people often think of `for` loops over `range`s as being "like C `for` loops" and mistakenly think it's incrementing the existing `i`, when it's really just producing a new `i` value from scratch on each loop).

If it helps, you can think of the Python `for` loop as behaving like a C++ for-each loop of the form:

```
for (auto i : sequence) {

}
```

Just like in Python, reassigning `i` inside that loop wouldn't change the value of `i` on the next loop, because it's *replacing* `i` with the new value from `sequence`.

If you want a C-style `for` loop in Python with arbitrary levels of control over the loop index, you're stuck simulating it with `while` loops, e.g.:

```
i = 0   # Initialize
while i < len(animals)-1:  # Test
    if(i == 0 and animals[i]!="grass" and animals[i]!="leaves"):
        if animals[1]  in animals_dict[animals[0]]:
            a=animals.pop(1)
            animals_final.append(f"{animals[0]} eats {a}")
    elif(animals[i]!="grass" and animals[i]!="leaves"):
        if animals[i-1] in animals_dict[animals[i]]:
            a=animals.pop(i-1)
            i-=1
            animals_final.append(f"{animals[i]} eats {a}")
            i=0
        elif animals[i+1] in animals_dict[animals[i]] and i+1<=len(animals) :
            a=animals.pop(i+1)
            animals_final.append(f"{animals[i]} eats {a}")
            i=0
    i += 1  # Increment step; some i = 0 lines might need to be i = -1 to correct
```

Just for funsies, I'll show a really terrible way to do this with a `for` loop and a coroutine-generator function:

```
def resettable_range(start, stop):  # Not bothering to accept 1 or 3 arguments for simplicity
    while True:
        rng = range(start, stop)
        for i in rng:
            start = (yield i)
            if start is not None:
                break
        else:
            return  # Ran to completion without being sent a new value; we're done
        # If we got here, loop was broken, so we loop with new start value
```

With that defined, you can write a loop like:

```
range_gen = special_range(0, 10)  # Must have named variable to send to
for i in range_gen:
    if some_condition:
        range_gen.send(0)  # Resets to 0
    elif some_other_condition:
        range_gen.send(i)  # Next loop will use same i value
    elif some_third_condition:
        range_gen.send(i-1)  # Next loop will back up to prior i value
```

To be clear, I don't recommend this approach. It's somewhat magical, and not particularly efficient if you regularly have to change `i` for the next loop (because it has to keep building new `range`s), but it works. It might need to be even more complicated for your case though, since you'd need the ability to redefine the end of the range too (since the length of `animals` can change).

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. If I approach this problem pythonic, what can I use instead of a for loop?

Comment: @SoareStefan: There is no good solution when you need to arbitrarily mutate the index in unpredictable ways; the `while` equivalent I already provided is the best option. `for` loops just aren't made for unpredictable jumps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try to work with this approach

Comment: @SoareStefan If you think that this answer it's a good one and it solves your problem, you could _accept_ it ticking the check mark visible at the top–left  of the answer.

Comment: @SoareStefan: FYI, I added a bad solution that allows a `for` loop to mutate the iterator so you can back it up. I strongly discourage it, but it's the best you can do if you *insist* on a `for` loop.